# Complex optional string concatenation and formatting in C#

Tags: c#, .net

How would you construct a C# function that takes in several strings and concatenates/formats them in a complex pattern depending on whether they are null/empty? For example, let's say I have three strings A, B, and C, and want to return as follows:

```
+------+------+---------+---------------------------+
| A    | B    | C       | Result                    |
+------+------+---------+---------------------------+
| ""   | ""   | ""      | ""                        |
+------+------+---------+---------------------------+
| "4"  | ""   | ""      | "4p"                      |
+------+------+---------+---------------------------+
| "8"  | "15" | ""      | "8 - 15p"                 |
+------+------+---------+---------------------------+
| ""   | ""   | "blue"  | "blue section"            |
+------+------+---------+---------------------------+
| ""   | "16" | "red"   | "16p, red section"        |
+------+------+---------+---------------------------+
| "23" | "42" | "green" | "23 - 42p, green section" |
+------+------+---------+---------------------------+
```

As you can see, there are some format pieces that are added if a particular element exists, and others that depend on *multiple* elements. Does this all just have to be done by manual if statements and concatenation, or is there some tool that can assemble such strings?

Comment: Are there explicit rules for the "extras" in the output string? If not, I don't think there's a generic way to do that. If there are... I still doubt there are. Although I'd resolve it as a static helper method or extension method.

Comment: Also, I would *not* suggest doing it with if statements.  Go the object-oriented approach. Build a bunch of classes and customized string builders.

Comment: There are other combinations of the sequences above ? For example, what if A=4, B="", C="blue" ?

Comment: if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a)) sb.append(a);  SE is not a coding service.  What have you tried?

Comment: @KonradViltersten, yes, the rules are what a naive examination would give: e.g. add "-" if both A and B are not empty, add " section" if C is not empty, add "p" if either A or B is not empty. Although the given data is just an example, I'm interested in the general problem of formatting optional strings.

Comment: There are answers below here addressing your issue well enough. I just want to point out that the downvote is unfairly done and the close votes are prematurely cast, in my opinion. I gave +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something as simple as you've described, you can write a relatively small number of `if` statements. Or, you can create multiple format strings and select the proper one. There are only 8 different possibilities, so you could easily code this with an enumeration. Consider:

```
[Flags]
StringFormatFlags
{
    AExists = 4,
    BExists = 2,
    CExists = 1,
    FormatNone = 0,
    FormatC = CExists, // 1
    FormatB = BExists, // 2
    FormatBC = BExists | CExists, // 3
    FormatA = AExists, // 4
    FormatAC = AExists | CExists, // 5
    FormatAB = AExists | BExists, // 6
    FormatABC = AExists | BExists | CExists, // 7
};
```

You can then initialize a value based on the values of A, B, and C:

```
StringFormatFlags val = StringFormatFlags.FormatNone;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(A))
    val |= StringFormatFlags.AExists;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(B))
    val |= StringFormatFlags.BExists;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(C))
    val |= StringFormatFlags.CExists;
```

That will give you a value from 0 to 7, corresponding with one of the `Format` values in that enumeration.

Now, create 8 different format strings:

```
string[] FormatStrings = new string[]
{
    "{1}{2}{3}", // 0 - None
    "{1}{2}{3}", // 1 - C only
    "{1){2}p{3}", // 2 - B only
    "{1}{2}p,{3}", // 3 - B and C
    "{1}p{2}{3}", // 4 - A only
    "{1}p{2},{3}", // 5 - A and C
    "{1} - {2}p{3}",    // 6 - A and B
    "{1} - {2}p,{3}",  // A, B, C
}
```

And, finally:

```
string formattedString = string.Format(FormatStrings[(int)val], A, B, C);
```

The key here is that the number in braces (i.e. `{2}`) won't generate anything if the corresponding parameter is null or empty.

Comment: A slight optimization but about as good as I'm going to get, I think.